# How to write data in the dataframe into single .parquet file(both data & metadata in single file) in HDFS?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, biginsights

How to write data in the dataframe into single .parquet file(both data & metadata in single file) in HDFS?

```
df.show() --> 2 rows
+------+--------------+----------------+
| name|favorite_color|favorite_numbers|
+------+--------------+----------------+
|Alyssa| null| [3, 9, 15, 20]| | Ben| red| []|
+------+--------------+----------------+
```

`df.rdd.getNumPartitions()` - it has 1 partition

```
>>> df.rdd.getNumPartitions()
```

1

```
df.write.save("/user/hduser/data_check/test.parquet", format="parquet")
```

If I use the above command to create parquet file in HDFS, it is creating directory `"payloads.parquet"` in `HDFS` and inside that directory multiple files `.parquet` file, metadata file are getting saved.

Found 4 items

```
-rw-r--r-- 3 bimodjoul biusers 0 2017-03-15 06:47 
/user/hduser/data_check/test.parquet/_SUCCESS 
-rw-r--r-- 3 bimodjoul biusers 494 2017-03-15 06:47
/user/hduser/data_check/test.parquet/_common_metadata
-rw-r--r-- 3 bimodjoul biusers 862 2017-03-15 06:47
/user/hduser/data_check/test.parquet/_metadata 
-rw-r--r-- 3 bimodjoul biusers 885 2017-03-15 06:47
/user/hduser/data_check/test.parquet/part-r-00000-f83a2ffd-38bb-4c76-9f4c-357e43d9708b.gz.parquet
```

How to write data in the dataframe into single `.parquet` file(both data & metadata in single file) in `HDFS`rather than folder with multiple files?

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: use coalesce(1) to get single file

Comment: why do you need one file? if you need it just to move it along then use the .gz.parquet file as it should have everything you need. The other files are generated in the process for various things.

Comment: Hi @Ashish Singh, I have tried below two commands, df.coalesce(1).write.save("/user/hduser/data_check/test_3.parquet", format="parquet");

df.coalesce(1).write.parquet("/user/hduser/data_check/test_4.parquet"); These commands are also saving or writing as directory with parquet data file and metadata files.

Comment: Like this: hadoop fs -ls /user/hduser/data_check/test_3.pa‌​rquet

Found 4 items

-rw-r--r--   3 bimodjoul biusers          0 2017-03-15 09:02 /user/hduser/data_check/test_3.pa‌​rquet/_SUCCESS
-rw-r--r--   3 bimodjoul biusers        494 2017-03-15 09:02 /user/hduser/data_check/test_3.pa‌​rquet/_common_metadata
-rw-r--r--   3 bimodjoul biusers        862 2017-03-15 09:02 /user/hduser/data_check/test_3.pa‌​rquet/_metadata
-rw-r--r--   3 bimodjoul biusers        885 2017-03-15 09:02 /user/hduser/data_check/test_3.pa‌​rquet/part-r-00000-6593ef9d-45c1-49a3-9b23-a783a9075c24.gz.parquet

Comment: @ShivaRam did this answer your question, if yes please respond with the solution if you have

Answer (score 0):

Use coalesce(1) after write. it will solve your issue

```
df.coalesce(1).write
```

Comment: Your call order didn't work for me.  I had to do `df.coalesce(1).write`

Answer (score 0):

This should solve the problem.

```
df.coalesce(1).write.parquet(parquet_file_path)
df.write.mode('append').parquet("/tmp/output/people.parquet")
```